# PostgreSQL : cast string to date DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: string, postgresql, date, casting

I'm trying to cast a `CHARACTER VARYING` column to a `DATE` but I need a date format like this : `DD/MM/YYYY`. I use the following `SQL` query :

```
ALTER TABLE test 
ALTER COLUMN date TYPE DATE using to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

The result is a date like this : `YYYY-MM-DD`.

How can I get the `DD/MM/YYYY`format ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Thomas

Answer (score 135, accepted):

A `DATE` column does not have a format. You cannot specify a format for it.

You can use `DateStyle` to control how PostgreSQL emits dates, but it's global and a bit limited.

Instead, you should use `to_char` to format the date when you query it, or format it in the client application. Like:

```
SELECT to_char("date", 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM mytable;
```

e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT to_char(DATE '2014-04-01', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  to_char   
------------
 01/04/2014
(1 row)
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot ! I wanted to make sure that this was not possible through the to_date() function.

Comment: @wiltomap It isn't, because all `to_date` does is make a date from a string. The date doesn't have a format internally, it's just a number.

Comment: Is there any way to search through a DB this way? For example: `select to_char(DATE my_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from my_table order by (DATE my_column) desc`?

Comment: Am I missing something? I got ERROR:  function to_char(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @Luffydude Maybe you're not using PostgreSQL, but instead Greenplum, Redshift, Aurora, etc?

Comment: I am using postgresql, i found some other code elsewhere and it worked but thx anyway

Comment: @Luffydude Ah, your problem is you're probably using a bind parameter of text or varchar type, when you should be using one of `date` type. Try casting to `date` or using the correct bind parameter type.

Comment: @antjanus 
SELECT DATE(date_trunc('month', created_at)) FROM my_table;

Answer (score 9):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-formatting.html

```
SELECT to_char(date_field, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
FROM table
```

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT) says

> The output format of the date/time types can be set to one of the four
>   styles ISO 8601, SQL (Ingres), traditional POSTGRES (Unix date
>   format), or German. The default is the ISO format.

So this particular format can be controlled with `postgres` date time output, eg:

```
t=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-11-29 09:15:25.348342+00
(1 row)

t=# set datestyle to DMY, SQL;
SET
t=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 29/11/2017 09:15:31.28477 UTC
(1 row)

t=# select now()::date;
    now
------------
 29/11/2017
(1 row)
```

Mind that as @Craig mentioned in his answer, changing `datestyle` will also (and in first turn) change the way postgres parses date.

Comment: I tried `select now()::date` and it returns a date on one server and a timestamp on another. They're both running postgres 11.12.  I suspect that someone may have messed with the date casting or type functions on the server that returns timestamp but i have no idea how or where.  Any help investigating would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, it was because one server had edb_redwood_date set to 'on' and one had it set to 'off' see: https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/epas/latest/epas_compat_ora_dev_guide/01_introduction/01_edb_redwood_date/ the solution was `alter system set edb_redwood_date=off;  select pg_reload_conf();`

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to convert the returned date of a select statement to a specific format you may use the following:

```
select to_char(DATE (*date_you_want_to_select*)::date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Formated Date"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which type you require as output, but here are 2 quick examples based on an intervals:

- `SELECT (now() - interval '15 DAY')::date AS order_date` -> `2021-07-29`
- `SELECT to_char(now() - interval '15 DAY', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` -> `2021-07-29`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your date column is `order_date`:

```sql
SELECT (
    RIGHT(order_date, 4) 
    || '-' 
    || SUBSTRING(order_date, 4, 2) 
    || '-' 
    || LEFT(order_date, 2)
    )::DATE
FROM test
```

OR

```sql
SELECT CAST(
    RIGHT(order_date, 4) 
    || '-' 
    || SUBSTRING(order_date, 4, 2) 
    || '-' 
    || LEFT(order_date, 2)
    AS DATE )
FROM test
```