# How to change datestyle in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I know this has been asked many times but no matter what I try in PostgreSQL 9.4, the datestyle will revert to ISO,MDY within a minute or so. I require the date format:

```
SET datestyle to SQL,DMY;
Show datesyle;
```

E.g. dd/mm/yyyy ... - After entering this, the 'show' command displays SQL,DMY

```
SELECT NOW();
```

Displays the current date in correct format

Each time I apply this setting and look at my date column it still turns my input into yyyy-mm-dd. Then shortly after if i run:

```
Show datestyle;
```

It's back to ISO,MDY.

I have applied the datestyles in three other ways:

```
ALTER DATABASE "database" SET datestyle TO SQL,DMY;

ALTER USER "User" SET datestyle to SQL,DMY;
```

- postgresql.config - Changed the datestyle variable and restarted the server

I have spent hours looking up advice and tried editing LC_TIME and the results are the same.

Comment: Formatting of the output is always done by the SQL client you are using. Unless you are using `psql` you need to check the manual of your SQL client on how to change the display format of dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL : cast string to date DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301939/postgresql-cast-string-to-date-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the answer is here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html

To quote "*SET only affects the value used by the current session.*"

But I'm wondering why you are trying to force a default date style. Just use YYYY-MM-DD in all your interactions. It's the ISO standard! When the value is supplied externally, convert it with **to_date()** and to output format it with **to_char()**.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about the SET datestyle being temporary. I would like to use ISO but YYYY-MM-DD is confusing to look at, and we will be viewing/editing table data directly, not calling queries that can include t0_date() or to_char(). 

I'm just very surprised there isn't a simple setting to at least allow tables   to display dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to modify the "datestyle" attribute in postgresql.conf. In my case it's located in /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

Good luck!