# Producing date from year and month values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, concatenation

Hello I'm having two problems with converting a concatenated date value into an actual date.

I've tired looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301939/postgresql-cast-string-to-date-dd-mm-yyyy) to convert the concatenated value with `to_char(DATE ...)` but I keep getting odd dates. I think it is because my month does not have a zero padding in front of it.

This is my base query:

```
SELECT 

   expiry_month,
   expiry_year,
   to_date(CONCAT(expiry_year, expiry_month), 'YYYY/MM'),

FROM thisTable
```

Here is an example of the data output:

```
expiry_month    expiry_year   concatvalues
9               2018          20189-01-01   
1               2019          20191-01-01
5               2016          20165-01-01
3               2019          20193-01-01
10              2017          201710-01-01
2               2020          20202-01-01
```

I think I need to `LPAD()` my month value to get the correct date parsed. E.g. 01 not 1, and 05 not 5.

However when I try to LPAD the month values it does not work. I've tried:

`lpad(to_char(expiry_month),2,'0'),`

I get this error 'HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'

Which I don't understand because lpad is a function. Any suggestion on how to use `LPAD()`?

Thank you for the advice.

#### EDIT 1

I've tried to update the `to_date()` function with this code:

`to_date(CONCAT(payment_cards.expiry_year || ' - ' || payment_cards.expiry_month || ' - 01'), 'YYYY-MM-01')` and now it is throwing a different error:

`ERROR: invalid value "- " for "MM" DETAIL: Value must be an integer.`

I'm still thinking I need to pad the month date?

Comment: Which are the *types* of the columns `expiry_month`and `expiry_year` of your table? Are they integers? Is the month represented as an integer, or a date (the first day of the actual month)?

Comment: Also note the format pattern you are providing to the `to_date` function contains a `/`, but you are not including that in the concatenated value. Should probably match...

Comment: @joanolo both are integers.

Comment: @Glen, I'll post and edit to my code above.

Comment: Just try `CONCAT(expiry_year, '/', expiry_month), 'YYYY/MM')` and see if it works. You're specifying a '/' and it's not in your text, so, the whole text is taken as the year, and the month and day are taken as 1/1

Comment: @joanolo that worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: @Chef1075: I've modified the title of your question to actually focus on the core need (lpad() didn't actually have anything to do with your case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `'/'` missing:

```
SELECT

   expiry_month,
   expiry_year,
   to_date(CONCAT(expiry_year, '/', expiry_month), 'YYYY/MM') AS the_start_of_year_month

FROM thisTable ;
```

will produce:

```
expiry_month | expiry_year | the_start_of_year_month
-----------: | ----------: | :----------------------
           9 |        2018 | 2018-09-01             
           1 |        2019 | 2019-01-01             
           5 |        2016 | 2016-05-01             
           3 |        2019 | 2019-03-01             
          10 |        2017 | 2017-10-01             
           2 |        2020 | 2020-02-01
```

The date format is specifying '/' and it wasn't there, so, the whole text was taken as the year, and the month and day were taken as 1/1. `CONCAT('2018','9')` was just returning `'20189'` (which is a valid year).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2645611f5713313df1e333307768a347)*

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
make_date(year int, month int, day int)
```

like:

```
make_date(expiry_year, expiry_month, 1)
```

[Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html)