# How to convert 'dd-mm-yyyy' to 'dd-mmm-yyyy' in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, psql, date-conversion

I want to convert data format 'DD-MM-YYYY' (e.g., '31-03-2020' ) to 'DD-MMM-YYYY' (e.g., '31-MAR-2020').
Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Relate https://stackoverflow.com/q/24301939/12485639 . You might find a solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to first convert the non-standard date (`31-03-2020`, which is actually a `text` or `varchar` type, in Postgres terms),  to a `DATE` type with `to_date()`, then convert it to the format you're looking for (which again, is actually a `text` or `varchar` type):

```
postgres=# select to_char(to_date('31-03-2020','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY');
   to_char   
-------------
 31-Mar-2020
(1 row)
```

Or to make it a *little* more human-readable:

```
postgres=# WITH dt AS (SELECT to_date('31-03-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') mydate)
SELECT to_char(dt.mydate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') FROM dt;
   to_char   
-------------
 31-Mar-2020
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to convert the returned date of a select statement to a specific format  you may use the following:

```
select to_char(DATE (*date_you_want_to_select*)::date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') as "Formated Date"
```

In case you need to convert a specific date to a specific format you may use the following:

```
select to_char(DATE '2020-03-31', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') as "Formated Date"
```